# How do I completely hide the chart title in a HighCharts chart?

Tags: highcharts

I notice that:

```
  title: {
  text: title,
  }
```

Can customise the content of the title but what if I need a chart without title? What should I do? I try to remove those code above and I got a "Chart Title" instead of just having nothing - which is what I expected.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

```
title: {
    text: ''
}
```

or

```
title: {
    text: null
}
```

Comment: It can work but it's still using up some space. (It's like `visibility:invisible` comparing to `display:none`